# What are the inhabitants of the island Ireland called?

Tags: terminology

On the island Great Britain lives the English, the Scots and the Welsh - they are all called British.

What are the corresponding words for citizens of countries Eire, Northern Ireland and the island Ireland?

Edit: has this changed during the course of history?

Comment: Irish. The people living in the Republic of Ireland are called Irish. The people living in N.Ireland are British. I think this information is readily available on Wikipedia, let me know if it isn't :)

Comment: *Most of these were the Protestant **descendants of colonists from Great Britain**. However, a significant minority, mostly Catholics, were nationalists who wanted a united Ireland independent of British rule. **Today, the former generally see themselves as British and** the latter generally see themselves as Irish, while a distinct **Northern Irish** or Ulster identity is claimed both by a large minority of Catholics and Protestants and by many of those who are non-aligned.* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Ireland)

Comment: @Mari-LouA So there is no distinction between the island inhabitants and the citizens of the Republic of Ireland. Wikipedia's article about the island doesn't say anything about a common name for the inhabitants of the island.

Comment: Your question lacked the minimum basic research. Please edit, and add your previous comment IN the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no research done by OP.

Comment: @BillJ Did you see my comment two steps above yours?

Comment: The research must be in the answer, and you only commented when I prompted you. I suggested also that you edit the question and include your comment. So, did you see my comment after yours?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "what are they *called*?".  Do you mean: "What is their nationality?" One's nationality can be different from the country one is living in!  They may prefer to call themselves something else again.

Comment: Yes, it has "his changed during the course of history" - but that is not a question for this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a Q. about the English *language*. It may be a Q. about nationality - but that is unclear because nationality & place of residence can be unrelated.  Also, "what they call themselves" may be different from their nationality.

Answer (score 3):

Logical categories and the politics of national identity aren't a good combination. There's no single answer to satisfy everyone.

The people of Eire can simply be called Irish. This is also probably the best *single word* to describe the people of the island of Ireland.

Many of those in the North would also choose to be called Irish (and the right to that identity is important and enshrined in the peace process). Others in the North would be opposed to this - vehemently in some cases - choosing to be called British instead. Note that "British" refers to inhabitants of the United Kingdom, not just of Great Britain*; there is no term like "UK-ish". "Northern Irish" is another way of referring to the inhabitants of NI; this is broadly accepted, though some hardliners - quite possibly on both sides - would disagree with that too.

To illustrate how fundamental this can be, I have even known one or two people who ended up having to select "mixed race" as neither "Irish" nor "White British" alone (the closest available options) captured more than half their identity, and we're not taking about people with militant leanings.

---

* Though "British" also refers to only those of us in GB (which makes historic and etmylogical sense.

Comment: Note that ‘British’ _also_ (and historically speaking, primarily) refers to the island of (Great) Britain, rather than the whole of the UK. It, like so many other geographic/national/ethnic terms, is vague and ambiguous.

Comment: @Janus you're right, of course.  The was what I meant by "not just" but that's not the natural way to read it - I've added a footnote rather than restructure.  There are whole stories of national (? or tribal) identity bound up in the use of "British" to describe people born and bred on the Island of Ireland.

Comment: Note that this attempts to capture as much of the nuance as an English person reasonably can in a short-ish post.  I'm sure I've missed issues, both linguistic and political.

Answer (score -1):

You make an incorrect assumption that the people of Britain are British, regardless of ethnicity. Many Welsh, Scottish/Scots/Scotch and English people do NOT identify as British. You also missed the Cornish, and the Manx but they are on a totally different island from either. British technically refers to someone or something from the island of Britain, but is has also come to be a euphemism for England which people that are not English resent. The English can resent the term for perceived political correctness or due to national and ethnic pride.

Anyways, things from the island of Ireland can be called Irish, or Gaelic, which is the ethnic subgroup the Irish are in, or Goedilic (which is the same thing but more academic). If they identify with Britain or British heritage (and another name for Northern Irish is Ulster-Scots, because there were a large number of Protestant Scots transplanted to Ulster, northern Ireland) they could also be called British, although less technically accurately.

There is a pretty long list that you can call any one of these groups, everyone but the English are Celtic. The Welsh and Cornish are Brythonic. The English also get called Anglo-Saxons or Saxons (or Sassanach, which is Scottish for Saxon and a swear) or WASPs (white-Anglo-Saxon Protestant, basically means super white).

As for changes over history yes. The acceptable terms have changed with British political de-evolution (as it is called) as Ireland acquired it’s independence, Scotland and Wales acquired home rule and local Parliaments. In the 18th century, around the time of Union, there was a move to re-lable Scottish people “Northern English” (which is a bit different from Northerners from the North of England). English was used interchangeably with British to refer to anyone from Ireland or Britain (or the other associated islands). In the medieval period English writers often refer to Gaelic people as being Irish, even if they were Scottish. Shakespeare does this in MacBeth, so even well after the medieval period. There is also a complicated history of Viking and French immigrants in parts of Ireland and Britain, as well as Normano-Anglo (French people that were largely aristocratic) in Ireland. Arthur Wellesley, the Duke of Wellington, was from Ireland, but his family and culture was English and can be traced back to the Normans, who restricted the use of English in England for 250 years.

Comment: Gaelic/Goidelic and Brythonic are not ethnic subgroups; they are _linguistic_ subgroups. That’s not to say some won’t identify very strongly with them, but there is no ethnicity behind them. There’s no ethnicity behind English, Scottish, Welsh and the others either, for that matter, but those are at least _nationalities_ (regardless of ethnicity).

Comment: You seem yo be mistaking the distinction between ethnicity and nationality, as well as race. All are seperate. Nationality is the country to which you have citizenship, although in Britain Scottish can replace British. That is somewhat unique to Britain. Race is a largely made up way of identifying skin colouration and some facial features. Ethnicity refers to the cultural and linguistic group you come from. The Welsh, Irish and Scots are all Celtic ethnicallly, but they belong to different groups. The English are ethnically Germanic. They are also linguistic groups as well.

Comment: England, Scotland and Wales are all separate countries, and their demonyms are indeed all nationalities. Race does not really play into things. The Gaels would be an ethnic group, but Goidelic is not; it is **uniquely** a linguistic group. You are mistaken in saying that Gaelic and Goidelic are the same thing; they are not. Gaelic is sometimes used to mean Goidelic, and in such cases it is not an ethnicity. You might at a stretch call Brythonic a split ethnicity, but there is very little pan-Brythonic identity left. It’s more a historic ethnicity.

Comment: Also, the people of Britain (if we take that to mean either citizens of the UK or citizens of one of the countries situated on the island of Great Britain) are indeed British regardless of their ethnicity. An ethnicity does not do away with a nationality.

Comment: The Bretagne and the Six Celtic Nations would disagree, as would any Gaelic person that wanted to draw a distinction from other Celtic groups with out explicitely targeting the Welsh. But yeah, Brythonic does see less distinction, it is still an ethnicity. Goidelic is the old Irish word for Gaelic, and is used historically to refer to Gaelic people (or the Goidelics) as their ethnicity.

Comment: I never said that having an ethnicity and nationality were mutually exclusive, I in fact explained how a Scottish person could be Celtic, British, Scottish and Caucasian at the same time. They could also be Indian instead of Celtic and Caucasian, or Celtic-Indian. What term they choose to use to express their identity is another matter and studies have shown disdain for the term British. Most people do not draw distinctions between ethnicity, race or nationality as most people did not study anthropology and dislike being put into simplistic boxes by other people. They like to do it themselves.

Comment: You should perhaps edit the first sentence in the answer to clarify that – as it stands, you do effectively start off by saying that not all Brits are British, which they are, by nationality (though, as you go on to say, not necessarily by ethnicity or identity).

Comment: Many Brits choose not to identify as Brits, not understanding that it merely refers to coming from “the island of tin”, or understanding and choosing to dislike it for political, ethnic and religious reasons. The OP makes the incorrect assumption that any Scottish, Irish or English person person can be called British without offending them. The second sentence explains that it is identity,  and the wording suggests self identity, without teaching the whole lesson on cultural identity from first year anthropology I went through with you.

Comment: Yes, and some Brits choose to identify as Martians. That does not change the fact that they are British (by nationality) if they are citizens of the UK. Their self-identification cannot change that. That has nothing to do with cultural identity. Your answer is severely conflating nationality, ethnicity and language, and since you do not seem inclined to edit it to reduce this conflation, I’ve downvoted it accordingly.

Comment: The topic at hand is not “what nationality are Irish people”, but “what is the appropriate thing to call them as I would call a British person?”. To which I reply that a British person might not like being called a British person any more than an Irish person might like being called British. You are also misuing the word conflate and ironically you conflated linguistic groups and ethnic groups together and started an off-topic arguement over anthropology which you clearly did not understand. Downvote me as you like, does not make any of your inaccurate statements about cultures true.

Comment: Also worth nothing that in Britain your nationality is not in fact British. Scottish, Welsh and English are also considered nationalities, which is why they all have seperate national football teams for instance. British citizenship is distinct from British nationality, due to the unique form of the British Commonwealth, which starts to get complicated with things like the Falklands, Gibralter, Jersey and the Channel Islands. Such people people are not British in the literal sense, nor were they legally until only a few decades ago, some of the older generations might still not be.

Comment: Anyways, the OP is asking not about nationality, as the people of the island of Ireland do not have a united nationality. What to call people from Ireland is Irish, not because that is their nationality but because that is their culture. AND culture is based on self identity. Also worth noting you cannot that a British passport is not even called a British passport but a passport of “the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland”. Someones from Jersey gets one that says “British Islands”, although they do have the same citizenship nowadays,

Comment: @LoganRoku Cornish and Manx don't live on the island Great Britain, hence they are not British.